# How to access parent data inside a nested data in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I'm doing data visualization with `d3.js` for some nested data , and the problem is at some point I need to get access to the parent data. for e.g accessing the student's name after the second pass of `.data( d=>d3.entries(d["grades"]) )`.

```
var data = {
"students": [
         {
           "Name": "Alex",
           "grades": {
           "8.0": 80,
           "10.0": 67,
           "9.0": 68,
           "5.0": 60,
           "3.0": 56,
           "1.0": 66,
           "7.0": 68,
           "4.0": 50,
           "0.0": 77,
           "6.0": 70,
           "2.0": 58 }
 },             
{   
"Name": "Anne",
"grades": {
          "5.0": 60,
          "10.0": 84,
           "4.0": 82,
           "0.0": 90,
           "2.0": 86,
           "8.0": 82,
           "3.0": 98,
           "1.0": 75,
           "9.0": 57,
           "7.0": 69,
           "6.0": 88}
     }
]};

svg.selectAll('g')
.data(data["students"])
.enter()
.append('g')
.attr("class","g2")
.selectAll('.g2')
.data( d=>d3.entries(d["grades"]) )     
.enter() 
.append('circle')
.attr('cx',v=>xscale(v.key))
.attr('cy',yscale(d.Name) ) //here I need d.Name
.attr('r', v=>sqrtScale(v.value) )
.style('fill', 'red');

undefined value for yscale(d.Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are passing in the the results of `d3.entries()` on `d['grades']` when you are trying to join the data. According to the D3.js documentation, [d3.entries()](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#entries)

> Returns an array containing the property keys and values of the
>   specified object (an associative array). Each entry is an object with a key and value attribute, such as {key: "foo", value: 42}

Therefore, doing you are only passing in the key-value pairs within `grades`, and you won't have access to `Name` on the subsequent `enter()`, which you have chained to the data join. Therefore, I would recommend you to map the results of `d3.entries()` with the `Name` property, such that each object within the array will contain `key`, `values`, and `Name`.

```
svg.selectAll('g')
  .data(data["students"])
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr("class", "g2")
  .selectAll('.g2')
  .data(d => (d3.entries(d["grades"]).map(obj => {
    obj['Name'] = d['Name']
    return obj;
  })))
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('cx', v => {
    return xscale(v.key)
  })
  .attr('cy', d => {
    return yscale(d.Name)
  })
  .attr('r', v => {
    return sqrtScale(v.value)
  })
  .style('fill', 'red');
```